# How can i make a .war file that works Jboss to work under Jetty web server?

Tags: jboss, jetty

How can I make a .war file that works Jboss to work under Jetty web server? I have a war file that is working under JBOSS webserver; However I want to deploy it under jetty but its giving me the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:995)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:202)
at org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter$GZIPResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(GzipFilter.java:265)
```

How can I make the follwing war file compatible to jetty web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in a lot of things... first thing i would do is to compile the war changing the server runtime in my project (in case of using eclipse) so the references on the classpath change from jboss to jetty (im thinking on jetty as a server like jboss web, GF or Tomcat)  then i would check if there is not any reference problem with the change of server runtime in my project, if there is any, then i would do the respective corrections, and try to deploy on jetty now :)

There's my two cents. :)